# How to use File.AppendAllText?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

this may sound like a stupid question to some but I am fairly new to Selenium and C# and I found this solution from github that is aligned with a project I am starting but when I run the test in the solution I get error:

> Additional information: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\sf.log'.

sf.log is not included in the solution and honestly do not know what to have in the log if I have to get one. Please I will appreciate any help on this. Thanks!

```
 capability.SetCapability("browserstack.user", username);
  capability.SetCapability("browserstack.key", accesskey);

  File.AppendAllText("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\sf.log", "Starting local");

  if (capability.GetCapability("browserstack.local") != null && capability.GetCapability("browserstack.local").ToString() == "true")
  {
    browserStackLocal = new Local();
    List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> bsLocalArgs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>() {
      new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key", accesskey)
    };
    browserStackLocal.start(bsLocalArgs);
  }

  File.AppendAllText("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\sf.log", "Starting driver");
  driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("server") + "/wd/hub/"), capability);
  return driver;
}
```

Comment: The path you specify to `AppendAllText` should be the path to a file that you want to append text to. It will create the file if it doesn't exist, but the path must exist. Are you running as the user `Admin`? The error is telling you that the directory `c:\Users\Admin\Desktop` cannot be found.

Comment: @RufusL Got it! thanks.. I just realized that solution also has another dependency: Browserstack, I don't think I will be needing that. I just want a solution with just Selenium Webdriver and Specflow. I will continue to search

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to write to the user's desktop, you can use the `Environment` class to get what you need:

```
// Determine the folder name using the desktop path and our .exe name
var rootDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
var thisExeName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
var fileDir = Path.Combine(rootDir, thisExeName);

// Create the folder if it doesn't exist
if (!Directory.Exists(fileDir)) Directory.CreateDirectory(fileDir);

// Now create a variable to store the path to our log file
var fileName = "sf.log";
var filePath = Path.Combine(fileDir, fileName);
```

However, if you're just logging information, you might instead use the `AppData` folder, which is more common for that:

```
// Determine the folder name using the AppData path and our .exe name
var rootDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

In either case, you now have a valid path to create your file, and you should be able to do something like:

```
File.AppendAllText(filePath, "Starting local");
```